# Why shouldn't I use attribute routing in a traditional (non API) controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been using attribute based routing in an API controller project:

```
[HttpGet("products/{productId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductDetails(int productId) {
  ...
  return Ok(someModelToSerializeAsJson)
}
```

This works great.  I find it much clearer and less error prone than conventional route table based routing.  I kept wondering why we can't use attribute based routing for MVC (non API) projects with views.  I tried this for a small non public facing web application and it seems to work great.  You have to mark the controllers as [ApiController], but you can still return views in the action methods.

```
[HttpGet("products/{productId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductDetails(int productId) {
  ...
  return View(someModelForTheView)
}
```

I would like to make the same choice for our main public facing website, but I'm worried I'm missing a solid reason why I shouldn't.

As an example, I've noticed that API controllers aggressively turn off HTTP caching (e.g. cache-control: no-cache, no-store).  That is a quirky issue to work around.

Are there other clear reasons to NOT use attribute based routing with MVC views?

Comment: Where did you read that you can't use attribute based routing for MVC? It's totally possible. As a general rule, I use the `ControllerBase` base class for API controllers and the `Controller` class for view controllers. You don't need the `[ApiController]` attribute.

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by "API controllers aggressively turn HTTP caching"?

Comment: @Ben Mills: See [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0). This post cover both *Conventional routing* and *Attribute routing*.

Comment: @DavidG, I missed the word "off"  I just edited for clarity.  I think that comes from using an ApiController.  If I can use a regular controller with attribute based routing, then I might not have that problem.

Comment: @Métoule, I'm not 100% sure where I got that information.  I hope you are right and I can simply use attribute based routing with regular controllers.   I will do some more experimenting.  Maybe other disagree, but I'm surprised Microsoft aren't aggressively replacing conventional routing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was wrong.  You can use attribute based routing for regular MVC controllers.  I thought you had to use an `ApiController`, but that is not correct.  The trick for me was that the base class for my controller needed to be `Controller` instead of `BaseController`.  Shout out to @Métoule for that nugget of information.